# How can i change url structure of cpt like this?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting

i have two examples what i exactly want.

Example 1: 
http://btbfootballtips.com/tips-prediction/?date=2016-05-01

Example 2: 
http://www.freesupertips.co.uk/previews/?date=2016-04-30

You see, they filter post/page or custom post type by date. anyone can tell me how can i filter post/page/cpt and set the url like this (?date=xxxx-xx-xx).

regards.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do the following:

- Identify the template being used to output your custom posts (or create one)
- Within this template, intercept the $_GET variable for date, sanitise it and parse it into a date that you can use in your posts query.
- Query the items (if you're using the post date for date, you can use that; otherwise you can use a meta query to query on a meta value if you're doing it that way).

Along the lines of

```
$day = date('d',strtotime($_GET['date']));
$month = date('m',strtotime($_GET['date']));
$year = date('Y',strtotime($_GET['date']));
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'year' => $year,
  'monthnum' => $month,
  'day' => $day,
  'post_type' => my_post_type,
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'orderby' => 'post_date',
  );
$myitems = get_posts($args);
```